# ¿Como bloquear escritura en un input date?

Tags: html, html5, date

Quisiera saber como hacerle para que en mi `<input>` date no pueda poner la fecha con el teclado, solo seleccionándola con el calendario que da el atributo, un ejemplo en la imagen, si escribo 29 si me deja ponerlo, lo cual yo solo quiero que se ponga mediante el calendario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FechaFin, new { @class = "control-label" })
     @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FechaFin, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-controlPortal", @readonly = "readonly" } })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FechaFin, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
     <label id="fechaFinRequired" class="text-danger label-required" for="Name">Requerido</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer muy simple agregándole lo siguiente a tu input:

```
onkeydown="return false"
```

y el `<input>` te quedaría así:

```html
<input type="date" value="2019-06-29" onkeydown="return false" >
```

Y así ya no se puede cambiar su valor con el teclado, solo con el calendario, saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias, funciono tal como lo necesitaba

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases el `onkeydown` a js para que no puedan evitar la restricción simplemente haciendo inspeccionar elementos.

Answer (score 0):

Con JQuery:

```
$('.input-date').keydown( () => {
    return false;
});
```